# Never act rudely toward your parents OR Never act saucily toward your parents

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which one of the following choices sounds natural:

> Never act rudely toward your parents. 
>   Never act saucily toward your parents.

If neither works as a natural way to say that, I would be thankful if you paraphrase it for me and tell me what is the commonest way to say that.

Comment: The meanings are different, so what is the context around these statements? In any case, if you check the definitions of *rudely* and *saucily* the difference should be clear. They both "sound" OK, but may not have the meaning you intend.

Comment: In accordance with my dictionary these two adverbs (rudely / saucily) mean exactly the same. This is why I decided to embed them in these two sentences to make sure about the proper usage of each one. Just I wonder if you tell me how these two adverbs differ? (What's their meaning?)

Comment: *Never* suggests a strong assertion, about the same as *Don't be*. I'd suggest something like *"Never be rude to your parents."*

Comment: @A-friend, **I think it would be very helpful for you to add a lot more context. In a sense, there is no single "natural" way to say anything.** For example, I might stop someone on the street and say, "Excuse me, do you have the time?" but I would never stop someone on the street and say, "Never act rudely towards your parents."  Without knowing the context, it's difficult/impossible to paraphrase a random sentence.  Also, are you wanting answers to be focused on a particular form of English, such as AmE or BrE? I'm from the USA and have never heard anyone say "saucily" in any sentence.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Thank you very much. It was really a great help. Now I'm sure the adverb "saucily" is probably mostly used in BrE. Meanwhile I will try to add more contexts from now on. Moreover I am studying and focusing on AmE. ;)

Comment: @A-friend, no problem.  I noticed that BrE influences in some of your questions - that might be related to your study materials / dictionary / learning process. I *hope I'm not being too forward* (I only intend to be helpful), but in looking at some of your questions, some seem so specific/narrow that I question if this approach is really good for you.  What do you gain by understanding "rudely" vs. "saucily" in such a sentence? What caused this to be a question of concern? Where are you in terms of English skills, where do you want to be, and what's the best way to get there?

Comment: You are quite welcome @CoolHandLouis. Now I realized the meaning of being too forward. It was really helpful. :)
I just didn't understand you in this comment. Do you need some information about me? ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Never act rudely toward your parents.

is perfectly fine, but a bit rigid like something a schoolmarm would say to a child.

Because 'saucy' has a sexual undertone, it would be weird or creepy to use in reference to parents.

There is a similar word, sassy, which is fine.  In some regions of the US, you will hear "Don't sass your mother/father."

Comment: Perfect. Is it an informal synonym for disrespect someone, which is a formal verb or as I see in dictionary "to sass someone" means only (to talk) rudely to someone who you should respect?

Comment: "informal synonym for disrespect someone" - sure that works.  Also, "sassy" us usually restricted to describing children.

Comment: Excellent. In my dictionary this point about "sassy" had been mentioned; meanwhile I think "to sass someone" is also a reserved verb for children. Am I right? There is another verb "to diss someone". I think it is the best informal alternative for "to disrespect somebody". Am I right?

Comment: Adults say *sass*.

Comment: Diss is a pop-culture slang for disrespect. It's inappropriate in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems better.

The word *[rudely](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rudely)* can be used to express what you think but then *[saucily](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/saucy#saucy__22)* does not seem a preferred word here. Click on the words to see the meanings. No one would certainly act *saucily* toward their parents. :)

I was a little bit doubtful about the sentence structure but it's clear.